# How can I show these polynomials are not coprime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

$x, x-1$ and $x+1$ in  the ring $\mathbb{Z_6}[x]$

Here the $\mathbb{Z_6}$ is the commutative ring with unity

I can't show these polynomials are not coprime in  $\mathbb{Z_6}[x]$
. Please help me.

Comment: Define *coprime*.

Comment: @user26857, If the g.c.d of the three polynomials are $1$ pairwisely Then these polynomials are "coprime"

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Do you know how to find the gcd of two polynomials over a given ring?

Comment: If only "coprime" is mentioned , usually the gcd of all elements is meant. Otherwise , it is better to use "pairwise coprime". Hint : A common divisor of $a$ and $b$ also divides $a-b$. So which pair can have a gcd different from $1$ ?

Comment: What GCD are you talking about in $\mathbb Z_6[x]$? GCD is usually defined in integral domains. In commutative rings two elements are coprime if the ideal generated by them is the whole ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal $(x-1,x+1)$ equals the ideal $(2,x-1)$ and this is not the whole ring, otherwise $1\in(2,x-1)$, so $1=2f(x)+(x-1)g(x)$. Now send $x$ to $1$ and get a contradiction.